# Typing effect for list of strings. Need help fixing order of events

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the following code to type/untype each string, one at a time, in the order they are listed. Currently, it executes, but the i++ is firing too many times within the loop and breaking the order of events. Please help correct the iterations so that any amount of strings may be typed/untyped in order.

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <h1>Innovative Solutions
        <br>for
        <span id="str"></span>
    </h1>
    <hr>
    <p>This is filler content. The text in this area will be replaced when copy for the site becomes available. This is filler content. The text in this area will be replaced when copy for the site becomes available.</p>
    <a href="#">Learn More</a>
</div>



$(function() {

  var speed = 200;
  var speed2 = 50;
  var str = document.getElementById('str');
  var i = 0;
  var isRemoving = false;

  var messages = [
    "Cyber Security...",
    "Vulnerability Assessments...",
    "Program Management...",
    "Compliance Management..."
  ]

  function action() {
    console.log('Action')

    if (isRemoving) {
      if (str.innerText.length > 0) {
        str.innerText = str.innerText.substr(0, str.innerHTML.length - 1);
        setTimeout( action, speed2 );
        return;
      }
      isRemoving = false;
      i++;
      if (i === messages.length) {
        i = 0;
      }
      setTimeout( action, 500 );
      return;
    }

    var message = messages[i];

    str.innerText = message.substr(0, str.innerHTML.length + 1);
    if (str.innerText.length === message.length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        isRemoving = true;
        console.log(isRemoving)
      }, 2000)
    }
    setTimeout( action, isRemoving ? speed2 : speed );
  }

  setTimeout( action, speed ) ;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would aim to only have one occurrence of `setTimeout` in your code. Make all the rest dynamic, and pass the *state* to each next call of `action` (use `bind` for this).

Here is how that would look:

```js
var str = document.getElementById('str');

var messages = [
    "Cyber Security...",
    "Vulnerability Assessments...",
    "Program Management...",
    "Compliance Management..."
]

function action(idx, len, dir) {
    str.textContent = messages[idx].slice(0, len);
    if (len % messages[idx].length == 0) dir = -dir; // Change direction
    setTimeout(
        action.bind(null, (idx+(len==0)) % messages.length, len+dir, dir), 
        len == messages[idx].length ? 2000 : dir < 0 ? 50 : 200 // Delay
    );
}

action(0, 1, 1); // Not really useful to have setTimeout here. Just call it.
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <h1>Innovative Solutions
        <br>for
        <span id="str"></span>
    </h1>
    <hr>
    <p>This is filler content.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't want to rework** your whole code, you can call your `i++;` just when the message is fully typed (`str.innerText.length === message.length`)

```js
$(function() {

  var speed = 200;
  var speed2 = 50;
  var str = document.getElementById('str');
  var i = 0;
  var isRemoving = false;

  var messages = [
    "Cyber Security...",
    "Vulnerability Assessments...",
    "Program Management...",
    "Compliance Management..."
  ]

  function action() {
    console.log('Action')

    if (isRemoving) {
      if (str.innerText.length > 0) {
        str.innerText = str.innerText.substr(0, str.innerHTML.length - 1);
        setTimeout(action, speed2);
        return;
      }
      isRemoving = false;

      setTimeout(function() {
        action();
      }, 500);
      return;
    } else {

      var message = messages[i];
      console.log(i);
      str.innerText = message.substr(0, str.innerHTML.length + 1);
      if (str.innerText.length === message.length) {

        i++;
        if (i === messages.length) {
          i = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
          isRemoving = true;
          setTimeout(action, isRemoving ? speed2 : speed);
        }, 2000)

      } else {
        setTimeout(action, isRemoving ? speed2 : speed);
      }
    }
  }

  setTimeout(action, speed);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <h1>Innovative Solutions
    <br>for
    <span id="str"></span>
  </h1>
  <hr>
  <p>This is filler content. The text in this area will be replaced when copy for the site becomes available. This is filler content. The text in this area will be replaced when copy for the site becomes available.</p>
  <a href="#">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Andre's answer was quick and got the job done.
Trincot, thank you for your response! I will probably implement this shortly in the future. Thank you both very much for quickly helping me solve this!

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to "Vote up" useful answers and to mark resolving answers ;)

Comment: I voted both answers up but my influence is not high enough for it to show yet.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

    var speed = 200;
    var speed2 = 50;
    var str = document.getElementById('str');
    var index =0;
    var isRemoving = false;
  
    var messages = [
      "Cyber Security...",
      "Vulnerability Assessments...",
      "Program Management...",
      "Compliance Management..."
    ] 
   
    
    function getIndex(index1){  
   
    if(index1===messages.length){
        return(0)
    }
    else{
        return(index1);
    }
}
    function action(){  
     
    if(isRemoving){  
        str.innerText = str.innerText.substr(0,str.innerHTML.length - 1);
        if(str.innerHTML.length===0) {
            index=getIndex(index+1);
            isRemoving=false;        
        }      
        setTimeout( action, speed2 );        
    }
    else{      
        str.innerText = messages[index].substr(0, str.innerHTML.length + 1);
        if(str.innerHTML.length===messages[index].length){
           
            isRemoving=true; 
        }         
        setTimeout( action, speed );
       }  
       
    }    
  
    setTimeout( action, speed ) ;
  });
```

```html
  <div class="flex-container">
    <h1>Innovative Solutions
        <br>for
        <span id="str"></span>
    </h1>
    <hr>
    <p>This is filler content. The text in this area will be replaced when copy for the site becomes available. This is filler content. The text in this area will be replaced when copy for the site becomes available.</p>
    <a href="#">Learn More</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```